# CollectionView not populated?

Tags: wpf, icollectionview

I've used ICollectionView a few times and never had any problems... but I can't get this one to work.

In my constructor I do the following:

```
    _viewModels = new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>();

    var icv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_viewModels);
    MyCollectionView = icv;
```

The one thing that I think is different is that I populate my _viewModels with a separate call.  So with a button for example after the app loads.  Even if I call MyCollectionView.Refresh() though at that time, and _viewModels has objects in it, MyCollectionView is still empty.

Should this work?  If so what am I missing and what can I look for?

Comment: *I've used ICollectionView a few times and never had any problems*... then just follow your earlier working examples.

Comment: I'm not sure about .net 4 but int 4.5 iv'e come to a conclusion that Refresh() , just does nothing . 

I just recreate it in the getter .

Comment: @Sheridan yep that's what I did.

Comment: @eranotzap You hit it on the head.  Refresh does indeed seem to do nothing- grabbing the view again seems to work.  I wonder if it's been deprecated for ICollectionViewLiveShaping?  Docs don't say it's deprecated though. Post this as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if Refresh does nothing in .Net 4.5 i haven't tried it on 4 so i can't say for sure when it stopped working , if it ever did . 
What i like to do is :

```
     public ICollectionView MyCollectionView
     {
        get 
        {              
            return new CollectionView(SourceCollection); 
        }
     }
```